# Cannot use enum in Angular Routes

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, aot

To avoid issues with typos with route or navigation, In a deeply nested app with many routes, trying to use enums or constants for route paths

```
export enum AppRoutes {
    MAIN = 'mainView',
    MAIN_SUB = 'mainView/SubView'
}
const registrationRoutes: Routes = [
    {
      path: AppRoutes.MAIN,
      component: ..
      children: [
        {
          path: '',
          component: ..
        },
        {
          path: AppRoutes.MAIN_SUB.substr(AppRoutes.MAIN_SUB.indexOf('/') + 1),
          component: ..
        },
        {
          path: `${AppRoutes.MAIN_SUB.substr(AppRoutes.MAIN_SUB.indexOf('/') + 1)}`,
          component: ..
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

This works perfectly fine with `ng serve` and compiled code without `aot` enabled. However, with `production` code or with `aot` enabled it always results like following where `path` attribute is omitted by compiler.

```
{
    path: "",
    component: A
    children: [{
        path: "",
        component: sn
    }, {
        component: Pn
    }, {
        component: An
    }]
}
```

I have tried to use `enum`, `const`, `static` property of `component` etc but result is always same.

Trying to figure out if something is wrong with code or it is AOT behavior...

Comment: could you find an answer?